# M.c.Escher and abstract thought

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning

The lithographs of dutch artist M.C. Escher have been used in the study of artificial Intelligence. How can the human mind Incorporate these optical illusions into abstract thought? Is this reverse artificial intelligence?

Comment: Welcome to ai.se...Great question....Can you link some works in the question?

Comment: @mico I deleted your comment, but that's a really cool link!

Comment: I did a quick search for Escher and AI, but aside from Hofstadter (who I have found to be extensively cited in an array of subfields) I'm not coming up with all that much.  This is a very interesting question, so, if you can add some links or excerpts, that would be greatly appreciated.  (PS- [Monument Valley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monument_Valley_(video_game))!!!)

Answer (score 1):

It is not reverse-artificial-intelligence .not only escher , almost all paintings can be interpreted into abstract thought , in fact that is what the brain does. Even when you read something your brain processes this into its mental language ("hermaneutics").

for more on "mental language" and "abstract thought" you should check https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8i61jl8OE3XdHRCSkV1VFNqTWc/view (geoff hinton is a noted researcher in this field (ai))